# Float subtraction returns incorrect value

Tags: c++

So I have a calculation whereby two floats that are components of vector objects are subtracted and then seem to return an incorrect result.

The code I'm attempting to use is:

```
cout << xresult.x << " " << vec1.x << endl;
float xpart1 = xresult.x - vec1.x;
cout << xpart1 << endl;
```

Where running this code will return

```
16 17
-1.00002
```

As you can see, printing out the values of xresult.x and vec1.x tells you that they are 16 and 17 respectively, yet the subtraction operation seems to introduce an error.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are xresult.x and vec1.x floats?

Comment: Are these values really integer 16 and 17? Where and how do they get defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point inaccuracy examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Comment: @Benjamin: How are the two questions in any way similar?

Comment: @Tomalak: Because the answers to one are the same as the answers to the other.

Comment: Both of those vector components are floats yes, though they are computed in a previous function which does have integer components

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley an identical answer does not make a question identical.  Only an identical question does.

Comment: @Benjamin: That the answers are the same is not at all relevant. Consider the questions "what is 10*5?" and "what is the number after 49?"

Comment: @Tomalak: Bad example.  Here's a better one. Consider the questions: "Why does 100000001.0f - 100000000.0f equal 0?" and "Why does 200000001.0f - 200000000.0f equal 0?".  Would you not close one of those as a duplicate of the other?  I most certainly would.

Comment: @Tomalak: And perhaps my phrasing was wrong when I said "Because the answers to one are the same as the answers to the other.", but I'm pretty sure you can get my point.

Comment: @Benjamin: I would too. That in no way applies here. I don't get your point at all. My example was a spot-on analogy. The duplicate proposal is incorrect.

Comment: @Tomalak: My point is this.  There are about 3 million ways to ask the question "Why are the results of my floating point calculations messed up?" sd75 provided one. I provided 3.  The solution is the same every time.  You provided it yourself.  It is to explain how floating point variables work.

Comment: @Benjamin: This question is "why are the results of my floating point calculations messed up?" The question you claim is a duplicate is a meta-question about how to teach the topic to people. It's _completely_ different. I'm starting to wonder whether you even read it. If you're going to pick a floating-point inaccuracy question to cite as a duplicate, you can do much better than that!

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't have time to sift through all the possible duplicates.  I looked at a few, and out of those, the one I chose had the best **explanation of how floating point variables work**.  And that's what I was looking for.  "How to teach people about the topic" to me, is pretty much the same as "Please explain the topic"

Comment: @Benjamin: Well that's a shame, because they're not the same. Again, it's not relevant what the answers are: duplicates are about the _question_. If you don't have time to pick the correct duplicate question, please don't suggest one. Closing questions is not a "best guess" feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called floating point arithmetic.  It is why numerical code is so "tricky" and filled with pitfalls.  That result is expected.  And what is more, it can depend on the processor that you're working with as to what and to what extent you'll see it.

I'd like to add that each type of variable of the floating point variables: float, double, long double have different precision factors.  That is, one may be more able to represent more accurately the value of the floating point number.  That is evidenced by how these numbers are held in memory.

When you look at a float, it contains less significant digits than say a double or long double.  Hence, when you perform numerics on them, you must expect that floats will suffer from larger rounding errors.  When dealing with financial data, developers often use some semblance of a "decimal."  These are much better designed to handle currency type manipulations with better accuracy of the significant digits.  It comes with a price however.

Take a look at the [IEEE 745-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) specification.

Comment: Your advice is generally useful, but I don't think it applies to this situation. 16, 17, and -1 are all exactly representable as floats.

It seems more likely that the problem is in the precision of the output stream. Imagine if the inputs are not precisely 16 and 17. Suppose they are (imprecisely, but that's irrelevant here) "15.99999" and "17.00001", and the output stream has previously had "std::setprecision(6)". To six decimal figures, the inputs are 16.0000, 17.0000, and the result is -1.00002. 

The better advice is to have OP use std::setprecision(10) so he can see what it going on.

Comment: This is not the problem here. As Rob already said, floats are _guranteed_ to be able to represent certain numbers exactly, including 16, 17 and -1.

Comment: @Gabriel Schreiber on what CPU?  Depending upon the processor architecture weird things can and do happen.  Although I would agree in that I like Rob's answer more than mine.

Comment: good question! Floats can hold those numbers on any machine that uses IEEE754 4-byte values for C `float`. I suspect that these numbers are exactly representable for any computer with a C++ compiler, but I don't have the standards at hand to check.

Answer (score 4):

> As you can see, printing out the
>   values of xresult.x and vec1.x tells
>   you that they are 16 and 17
>   respectively, yet the subtraction
>   operation seems to introduce an error.

No, it doesn't tell us that at all. It tells us that the input values are approximately 16 and 17. The imprecision might, generally, come from two sources: the nature of floating-point representation, and the precision with which the numbers are printed.

Output streams print floating-point values to a certain level of precision. From a description of the [std::setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/) function:

> On the default floating-point
>   notation, the precision field
>   specifies the maximum number of
>   meaningful digits to display in total
>   counting both those before and those
>   after the decimal point.

So, the values of `xresult.x` and `vec1.x` are 16 and 17 *with 5 decimal digits of accuracy*. In fact, one is slightly less than 16 and the other slightly more than 17. (Note that this has nothing to do with imprecise floating-point representation. The declarations `float f = 16` and `float g = 17` both assign exact values. A `float` can hold the exact integers 16 and 17 (although there are infinitely many other integers a `float` cannot hold.)) When we subtract slightly-more-than-17 from slightly-less-than-16, we get an answer of slightly-larger-than-negative-1.

To prove to yourself that this is the case, do one or both of these experiments.  First, in your own code, add "cout << std::setprecision(10)" before printing those values. Second, run this test program

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(i) <<
      15.99999f << " - " << 17.00001f << " = " <<
      15.99999f - 17.00001f << "\n";
  }
}
```

Notice how the 7th line of output matches your case:

```
16 - 17 = -1.00002
```

P.s. All of the other advice about imprecise floating-point representation is valid, it just doesn't apply to your particular circumstance. You really should read "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic".

Comment: Rob, your answer is very useful in highlighting the problem but you seem to understate the fact that the reason for the OP getting strange values is probably as a result of him using floats and not doubles.

Answer (score 3):

Its because of how floating points work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't accurately represent all numbers using a float. Wikipedia has a good description of it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 0):

If there was a small decimal portion on the 16 and 17 that wasn't printed out, when the values are normalized to the same base for subtraction, that could introduce extra error, especially for 32 bit types like `float`.

When you use floating point values, you need to be prepared within your application to deal with the fact that you won't get 100% accurate decimal results. Your results will be as accurate as possible in the internal *binary* representation. Addition and subtraction especially can introduce a significant amount of relative error for operands that are orders of magnitude apart and for results that should be close to 0.

Answer (score 0):

How much do you know about the way numbers are stored in a computer?

Also, what are xresult.x and vec1.x  - as in are they ints etc or floats.

I'd be suprised that if they were all floats the error occured, but you are converting between types and binary is not the same as decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Make your variables doubles instead of floats. Youl get more precision.

**EDIT**
Computers store numbers using a sequence of bits. The more bits you store the higher the precision of the result. In fact floats usually have half the number of bits as doubles so they have lower precision.

Comment: +1 helps solve the problem -1 doesn't tell the OP why this happens.

Comment: But it doesn't help solve the problem. 16, 17, and -1 all fit into floats exactly as well as they fit into doubles. The OP will get exactly the same text output regardless of his floating-point type.

Comment: That is true and in that case 16 should stay 16 and 17 should stay 17 unless they are used in a previous calculation which they must have been otherwise no error would have been introduced. Given this fact then the only reason errors would accumulate up to the 6th decimal place is because of insufficient precision.

Answer (score 0):

People keep talking about how computer representations cannot perfectly represent real numbers, and how computer operations on floating point numbers cannot be perfectly precise.

This is true, but the same is true of the real world.

Real measurements are approximations to some degree of precision.  Operations on real measurements result in approximations to some degree of precision.

If I count 17 bowling balls, I have 17 bowling balls.  If I remove 16 bowling balls, I have one bowling ball.

But if I have a stick that is 17 inches long, what I really have is a stick that is about 17 inches long.  If I cut off 16 inches, I'm really cutting off is about 16 inches, and what I'm left with is about 1 inch.

You have to keep track of the accuracy of your measurements, and the precision of your results.  If I have 17.0, accurate to three significant digits, and subtract 16.0, also accurate to three significant digits, the result is 1.0, accurate to two significant digits.  And that's what you got.  Your mistake was in assuming that the extra precision provided by your results, beyond the accuracy you were given, was meaningful.  It's not.  It's meaningless noise.

This isn't something specific to computer floating point numbers, you have the same issue whether using a calculator or working out the problems by hand.

Keep track of your significant digits, and format your answers to suppress precision beyond what is significant.