# Please explain how in PHP extending the %f dec. places can return the wrong answer in printf()?

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp

Thanks for checking this out people.
I'm learning PHP from "PHP for Absolute Beginners" book but can't figure why I get the wrong answer from the code below:

```
<?php
$amt1=2.55;
$amt2=3.55;
$total= $amt1 + $amt2;
echo'<br/>The total is $'. $total;
printf('<br/>The total is %.21f', $total);
?>
```

I get 6.099999999999644729 not 6.1000... (just imagine 20 zeros)
Using Eclipse/XAMP/MAC OSX Lion How can the computer lie like that- or (more likely) how can I keep it honest by writing better code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) have [limited precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262889/float-subtraction-returns-incorrect-value).  floats cannot represent all numbers (one or more of `2.55`, `3.55` or `6.10` is not representable precisely).  In situations where very high or exact precision is required, floats are the wrong data type.  You're best bet here is probably [round](http://php.net/round).

(On a technical note, "floats have limited precision" is a bit wrong.  What might be more accurate is "floats can only represent *some* numbers exactly.  Some numbers are impossible to represent with exact precision with a float.")

Comment: Ahh yes, I follow now- thank you. I appreciate the links too.